# Problem with FFT in Python for smaller df

Tags: data-cleaning, numpy

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Fs = 200                        # sampling rate
Ts = 1.0/Fs                      # sampling interval
t = np.arange(0, 1, Ts)            # time vector

f_f = np.arange(30, 80, 0.001)
a = np.arange(0, len(f_f), 1)
    
for i in range(len(f_f)):
    y2 = y2 +  np.sin(2 * np.pi * (f_f[i]) * t)

n = len(y2)        
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
frq = k/T               # two sides frequency range
freq = frq[range(int(n/2))]     # one side frequency range

Y = np.fft.fft(y2)/n                # fft computing and normalization
#Y = np.fft.fft(y2)
Y = Y[range(int(n/2))]
plt.plot(freq, abs(Y), 'r-')    # Fourier data 
plt.show()
```

Here, as you may have noticed I have chosen `df = 0.001` and the
corresponding DFT is shown in the attached pic. However, while I am
considering `df = 1` instead, DFT comes out as a sort of continuous square
wave over the frequency domain of the signal (expected since the amplitude
of all the waves is equal). Why is it then getting distorted for `df = 0.1` or smaller? I mean why two peaks are appearing at `f = 30 Hz` & `f = 80 Hz` and not the entire band?

Even, the sampling rate has been so chosen so that Nyquist rate exceeds maximum frequency component of the pulse.